# How to install openssl and sqlcipher using the script while creating the .pkg for the macOS

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew, sqlcipher, pkgbuild

I am trying to create the mac package, So i need to install `sqlcipher` and `openssl`. I am trying to install it with the brew, but i am getting error.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Function to install Homebrew
if ! command -v brew &>/dev/null; then
    echo "Homebrew is not installed. Please install Homebrew manually to continue."
    exit 1
fi

# Install sqlcipher and openssl using Homebrew
brew list sqlcipher &> /dev/null || brew install sqlcipher
brew list openssl &> /dev/null || brew install openssl

# Add export commands (for sqlcipher and openssl) here if needed

exit 0
```

how to solve it, Thanks in advance

- I have tried to provide the absolute path
- I have tried to install the homebrew